# Finding the last value of .length in a selectable()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-selectable

I'm running a selector in a table I have. And I have conditionals that hide/show buttons depending on how much is selected. But I ran into a problem.

```
selected: function (event, ui) {
    var slctd = $(this).find(".ui-selected > td:nth-child(1)").length;
    $("#batch_sel").html(slctd);
```

From here if i console.log the `slctd` it basically goes from 1 to number of selected rows. 
Thing is I have conditionals that  `if (slctd == 1) ...`  are broken if I select more then one (from log):

```
0
1
2
3
4
...
```

So if i select more then on ein this case it will still perform the `if (slctd == 1) ...`, plus additional conditions that I have set that activate if the `slctd > 1`.

Is there a way to just get the last value of .length, rather then all of the values until it reaches the one I need.

Any ideas?

**SOLUTION**

Use `stop: function` instead of `selected:` to get the last value of the .length. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
stop: function (event, ui) {
var slctd = $(this).find(".ui-selected > td:nth-child(1)").length;
$("#batch_sel").html(slctd);
```